# Copying contacts from one folder to another in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to be able to copy my contacts (about 5000 of them) from my suggested contacts folder in outlook and paste them into another folder. Every time I select all 5000 contacts, outlook freezes for about 30 seconds and I am unable to copy and paste them. I have selected all and clicked move to option but that only moves them. I just want to be able to copy and paste from one folder into another.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use our **free** [Copy/Move Outlook Items](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookItemsCopy/) utility. I recommend it because I'm one of its developers. With the tool you will be able to move all your contacts with a single click on a ribbon. Or even using contact folders' context menu.